# Assigning values to separate ranges

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

In Excel, I'd like to be able to assign a value to a cell from another cell, while still being able to edit the assigned cell without losing the formula and functionality. Is there any function capable of doing this, or should I use VBA? Also, could you provide examples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a tiny trick that can be applied either manually or through *VBA*.

Say we have a formula in cell **A1** that returns some numeric value.  We want the formula to remain in the cell to be used elsewhere, but we want the cell to *appear* to have the value of a label stored in cell **D1**.

We can change the **A1** format so that if the worksheet is viewed or printed, only the label will appear in **A1**.  Before:

[image]

Run this macro:

```
Sub ApplyFakeFormat()
    Dim DQ As String, msg As String
    DQ = Chr(34)
    msg = DQ & Range("D1").Text & DQ
    Range("A1").NumberFormat = msg & ";" & msg & ";" & msg & ";"
End Sub
```

To get this result:

[image]

If you can't use *VBA*, here is how you would setup the format manually:

[image]

Comment: @Duckapple  Just remember to re-run the macro if you change the label cell .

Comment: But the formula has no more effect there now? Who would you want to keep it?

Comment: @Aganju  **the formula is still there!!** ...............if you examine the Formula Bar in each of the pictures, you will see the formula............any other cell can still use the $10.00 value that **A1** contains.

Comment: yes, I did see the formula. I don't see the sense of keeping it there: If any other cell wants to use that formula's result, it could just use that formula instead. Basically, I don't see anything to gain by storing that formula here instead of where it is used.

Comment: @Aganju  The value of the technique is  something that only Duckapple can answer.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I get you right - after your edit, you would have a formula in that cell but a typed value that is potentially different than the formula's result? That is not possible, and makes very little sense.

Even with VBA (it does still not make sense) the value would be overwritten by the formula with the next recalculation.

A cell holds one thing, not two. A formula and its result is one thing, a typed value is another thing, you can't have both in one cell. Just use two cells.